# TDD how can I build this test? Not sure what to verify it against

Tags: .net, tdd, nunit, moq, console-application

I am using nunit, moq and trying to do TDD.

I have query that returns some user accounts. I have another query that gets back a collection of conditions.

I am to go through each account and check each account against the collection and see what condition(if any) that users account falls into.

```
public void Test()
{
  var accounts = GetAccounts();
  var conditions = GetConditions();

  foreach(var a in accounts)
 {
    var found = conditions.Where(x => x.condition1 >= a.condition1 && x.condition2 <= a.condition2).FirstOrDefault();

    if(found)
    {
      // move on to next condition in flow chart
    }
    else
    {
       continue;
    }
 }

}
```

How can I test this in TDD. I want to verify if the right condition is found? I don't see making this a public method would be wise and I don't see any point in my application of someone checking for a condition.

So I am not sure what to actually test as the this condition gets used later on to calculate a number and that is something I could use to verify if the right conditions where called. The thing is though that would basically mean the end of the method and the number could have been affected by any of the other stuff and would defeat how I understand TDD(you write the method one piece at a time but first making a unit test to test it)

**Edit**

Yes that is what I started to do. I made my mocks and fake objects. and had everything setup but then I got stuck on what the heck I would use to verify the results.
The method I am making is most likely going to stay void(it will either log errors or update the customers account at some point). It really is the only public method in the application as the application will run as a scheduled task(it is a console app) so it is basically the "run" method. It will have many private methods in the bussiness layer with all the business cases. In the end the user either gets skipped or if they meet the conditions they are penalized. 
The penalty will be updated to their account.

Yes I could make the conditions methods public or internal but I don't see that any method outside of the business layer should know about them. It is only relavent to that business layer and then on top of it only when that "run" method gets ran.

This is what makes TDD so hard for me. They say to only test public methods what is alright if I was making say a website that interacts with a user and most likely will send some sort of feedback to the user(ie success message/result). But when you got an application that should run as a scheduled task that just runs through one public method and the rest is just business rules it gets very hard for me to figure out how to test it.

What is SUT internal?

Comment: SUT = system under test. In your case, it is the rules engine. I said **make the SUT internal**, meaning you should make the rules engine's encapsulation internal (and expose internals to the unit test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any test, you will want to specify some fake dependencies (users and conditions, in this case), and compare the output of the function you are testing, with a predefined expected result (in this case, if I understood correctly, you want to verify that each account has the expected condition).

You can write a test that injects a fake users list, and a fake rules list into your SUT (System Under Test), and compare the actual list of users and their conditions, with the expected list.

Your test could look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Rules_matcher_with_premium_users_should_have_free_access()
{
    var customer = Mock<IAccount>>);
    var condition = Mock<ICondition>();
    customer.Setup(c => ...); // set up condition
    condition.Setup(co => ...); // set up condition
    var sut = new MyBusinessLogic(customer.object, condition.object);
    var result = sut.DoConditionCheck();

    Assert.AreEqual(condition.object.Id, customer.object.Condition.Id);
}
```

What I did here is an example of a test that states, as you said, that the customer should have the right condition. I used stubs for the condition and customer, and assuming that the rules-engine should works, the customer should *have* that condition.

As for encapsulation: According to most TDD purists, you only test the public API. Anything else will be tested as a side effect of being *called* by the public APIs that you test. If it is not public, it is an implementation detail, and need not be tested **directly**. If it needs to be tested, make it public.

I take a slightly more relaxed view. You can make the SUT internal, and expose it for unit tests using the **`InternalsVisibleTo`** attribute, and specifying the test assembly.

Comment: Whenever it is difficult to write the tests, it is most often because the production code is hard to test. If you want to write robust tests that verify the outcome of an operation, rather than the implementation, you should refactor the SUT to return a value. In your case I would refactor the rules engine to return the account with the applied condition, or the applying condition itself (as per my example). You would then architect your solution as a service whose main workflow contains engines (functions) that you can test.

Comment: You can write integrative tests to verify the outcome of the application as a whole (i.e. the public method), while writing unit tests for the internal functions that do the actual work. You can expose the internals to the tests. I believe it is a valid concession towards practicality. Just refactor your internal functions to return a deterministic result that you can compared to an expected one.

Comment: Well I am going application goes through 60,000+ account in one go. As I said I could make a method that returns the condition but the thing is I don't want to expose it as a public method or really anything outside of that business layer

Comment: Eventually I will write integrative tests to verify the outcome but right now I am just trying to verify my logic. I don't mind expsoing the methods to the tests but with internal keyword everything in the assembly my business layer class in will be able to access that method and that is what I have a problem wtih.

Comment: Maybe I am making too much of it but it just seems sort of wrong that you need to expose the method(at the minimum) to the assembly. Like I said it only that service layer should know about that method and reality it should only be calling those methods. I have however gone ahead and made them internal(what in this project really would be no diff then making it public as only got 2 projects..the console app and test project). But since I got to get this project down I exposed it this way. I still don't like it but I want to be able to test it and finish this project. I am still looking for a

Comment: You cannot really have it both ways - it is either an API that you need to test, and will therefore be public or **internally** public, or it is just an implementation detail and should **not** be tested, because the implementation may change without warning (and should just be made **private**). Another way to think of it, is that the unit test is a client, too. If it needs an API, then the API should be made public. The main thing is, that your difficulty is the **system's way of telling you to refactor your architecture**. Your encapsulation is working against your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a flow chart in your remarks. So, why not create a flowchart object and test against it. You will have a method like GetNextStep that receives an account and then you see the returned step is the step you expect.

Comment: I don't follow. Yes I could move the code to it's own method but i feel the method should be private and since you can't test proviate methods I still have the same problem. My application has like 2 public methods and will be a automated program that runs and all results get posted to the db(what will get mocked out). The thing is the object does not get created for a while until these pre conditions are met.

Comment: What I mean is that you can model the concept of a flowchart in an class called Flowchart. In this class you will have a method called GetNextStep that receives an account and the previous step the account was. This method will contain the logic you want to implement. You will test this method in your unit test. In this way you have an expected test for some account and you will have the step returned from the method. You simply compare them to know if the method returned the correct value. Hope that helps.